# Access localhost of PC from USB connected device and get ipv4

Tags: android, localhost, usb, ipv4

I want to access localhost of PC from USB connected device. I enable USB tethering but don't show ipv4 for connected device in ipconfig.
Yesterday i could see ipv4 but i disable device active network from 'network and sharing center' and after that, when i enable USB tethering, not shows ipv4.
What is my problem? and how can solve this?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You want to make a tcp-ip connection between your mobile and your desktop? If so, be usb cable connected or not - it doesn't matter, do this: 1) make your mobile able to access 3g-4g data (not wifi!!!!) ; 2) turn on portable hotspot on your mobile; 3) connect your desktop to the mobile hotspot like you would do with a regular wifi network. Following this you will be able to find ipv4 on/from both devices.